# Thread safe code

Tags: java, thread-safety

Is doing get on concurrent arraylist or concurrent map (call it MainMap)  and  doing write/update to it using the same index still a threads age operation

Comment: It depends on how the map is being modified in other parts of your code. But instead of having a map of maps, you should have a single map, whose key type is a pair of strings.

Comment: @JBNizet That's great idea. I updated my code above to reflect the modified portion. If someone is updating the same value that another thread is accessing from getMyValue, is this an issue? I am not sure if ConcurrentHashmap is solving this

Comment: @JBNizet btw your suggestion won't work if I need to know all values that Key1 Own. Right?

Comment: No, indeed. That would be a good justification for keeping your design.

Comment: In the update case, what happens if `mainMap.get(key1)` returns null?

Comment: Yea I should handle it, I am just putting an example to understand threadsafety

Comment: Right, but how you handle it affects the answer. One way to answer it would be to check if it's null, and if so, create a new map and put it in mainMap. They would leave your with a race condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is that the thread safety<sup>1</sup> depends on type of `mainMap` and how it is used by other threads.

- It will be safe if `mainMap` is a concurrent map.
- It will be safe if `mainMap` was safely published and is effectively
  immutable.
- Otherwise, it is not thread safe.

---

It is not sufficient to say that nothing else updates it at the same time as the current thread reads it.  You have to consider the memory model.

---

**UPDATE**

The extra code tells us that the code won't suffer from low level memory anomalies.  Whether it is strictly thread-safe depends on the precise specification of the intended semantics of the operations.

The problem is that you are performing atomic operations on two distinct data structures.  A sequence of atomic operations is not necessarily atomic.  Whether this matters depends on how you *expect* the getValue and setValue methods to behave.

---

<sup>1 - The classical definition of thread-safety is that a thread-safe program is one that behaves according to its specification for all executions that are *allowed* by the semantics of the language's (or language implementation's) multi-threaded execution model.  As you can see, it presupposes that there is a specification of some kind for the program itself.</sup>

Comment: I updated my code above to reflect the portion place it is modified. I assume that because Main is concurrentMap then everything is good. But from your answer, it seems this is not threadsafe as one can update the object while the other one is reading across 2 different methods.  If true, then how can the above example be made threadsafe.

Comment: hmm, well my concern here is the following.  Assume thread1 is processing the  overloaded toString method (which says is doing byte read/conversion). At the same time thread2 is doing putValue which is updating the same object. Will this cause an issue and if so how can this be avoided knowing that I don't have access to the class of object a ( I can only change the class above)

Comment: Your code is sufficient to guarantee that a `getMyValue` call will see either the "old" value or the "new" value.  But we can't say which one it will see if the  `getMyValue` and `updateMyValue` calls overlap in time.

Comment: Thank you. That is ok for my case. I just want to make sure I am not running into concurrency exception. However, if one thread obtained the object from the mainMap and is working on it while the other thread is updating mainMap by replaceing that object with another object. Wouldn't thread1 be dealing with corrupted object now since it processed half old object and half new object and get exception? Sorry if I am using wrong termonologies here